# representation of $M_n(\mathcal{A})$ into $M_n(B(\mathcal{H})$ is closed

Tags: operator-algebras

After having identified $M_n(B(\mathcal{H}))$ with $B(\mathcal{H}^{(n)})$ one could take a unital $C^*$ Algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and identifiying $M_n(\mathcal{A}$) by representing it as

$$ \pi : M_n(\mathcal{A}) \rightarrow M_n(B(\mathcal{H})) $$

where $\pi$ is a $*-$ representation. Is it immediate then, to say that the image of $M_n(\mathcal{A})$ under $\pi$ is closed, so that $\pi(M_n(\mathcal{A}))$ is a $C^*$ Algebra?

EDIT:

I think I found out (a part) by myself:

If I consider two $C^*$ Algebras $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ and a $*-$ homomorphism between them $\pi$, then I know its image will be the same as

$$\tilde{\pi}: \mathcal{A}/ker(\pi) \rightarrow B $$

where $\mathcal{A}/ker(\pi)$ is a $C^*$ algebra (cause $ker(\pi)$ is a closed two-sided ideal) and $\tilde{\pi}$ is injective(hence isometric), so by homomorphism theorems $\mathcal{A}/ker(\pi) \cong Range(\pi)$. Thus $Range(\pi)$ is a $C^*$ Algebra (hence norm-closed).

Can I say the same thing for $M_n(\mathcal{A}$) and $M_n(\mathcal{B})$?

Answer (score 1):

Without too much work you can show that $M_n(A)$ is closed. Namely, you can show that if $A$ is closed, then norm convergence in $M_n(A)$ is equivalent to entry-wise norm convergence in $A$. then, if $A$ is closed, so is $M_n(A)$.

Once you know that $M_n(A)$ is closed, your reasoning applies.

Comment: thank you, so you mean, taking $(a_{i,j})^{(k)}$ a Cauchy sequence, then it's like taking Cauchy sequences of all the single entries of matrix, but each of them converges to an element $\tilde{a}_{i,j} \in \mathcal{A}$ since $\mathcal{A}$ is norm-closed. So the limit of $(a_{i,j})^{(k)}$ is still an element of $M_n(\mathcal{A})$

Comment: Yes, and then you have to show that the sequence converges in norm to the limit.

Comment: I don't think there would be much to show, if what I said before is correct.. could you help me to formalize this?

Comment: Well, let me put it this way. If instead of $B(H^n)$ you consider $B(\ell^2(H))$, you can play the same game, but now the matrices of the operators are infinite. And it is **not** true that entry-wise convergence implies norm convergence in that case.